# How to automatically (when typing) expand and shrink columns of EditTexts to show all symbols?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

I have following code for creating tables where people input numbers (like in excel but more more simplified)

```java
public class Table extends Fragment {
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private EditText[][] editTexts;
    private int x, y;
    private int shape;

    Table(int shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    void setX(int x) {
        if (x > 0) this.x = x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    void setY(int y) {
        if (y > 0) this.y = y;
    }

    void refresh() {
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
        TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[y];
        editTexts = new EditText[y][x];
        for (int i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
            tableRows[i] = new TableRow(getContext());
            tableLayout.addView(tableRows[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < editTexts[i].length; j++) {
                editTexts[i][j] = new EditText(getContext());
                editTexts[i][j].setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                editTexts[i][j].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(shape, Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                editTexts[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
                editTexts[i][j].setMinEms(1);
                editTexts[i][j].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
                tableRows[i].addView(editTexts[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    String getElement(int x, int y) {
        return editTexts[y][x].getText().toString();
    }

    void setElement(String string, int x, int y) {
        editTexts[y][x].setText(string);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table, container, false);
        tableLayout = new TableLayout(getContext());

        FrameLayout frameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        frameLayout.addView(tableLayout);
        refresh();
        return view;
    }
}
```

But i have a problem: this table can`t auto resize its columns on-the-fly. For example, 
i typed some numbers and i get this:

Image 1 :

[image]

Then, i click back button on my phone and get this:

Image 2 :

[image]

My question is: how to get result as in picture 2 without pressing anything, i want to resize table columns **when i typing, not after this**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mainly Facing this issue because layout params are not set properly you should try setting layout params at this piece of code:

```
 void refresh() {
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
        TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[y];
        editTexts = new EditText[y][x];
        for (int i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
            tableRows[i] = new TableRow(getContext());
            tableLayout.addView(tableRows[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < editTexts[i].length; j++) {
                editTexts[i][j] = new EditText(getContext());
                editTexts[i][j].setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                editTexts[i][j].setLayoutParams(new 
                TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                editTexts[i][j].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(shape, Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                editTexts[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
                editTexts[i][j].setMinEms(1);
                editTexts[i][j].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
                tableRows[i].addView(editTexts[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```